# loop on subgroups in dataframe

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, grouping, subset

I received answer yesterday but there is one thing which is not working 100% correct. My dataframe SHORT:

```
ID  IDaxis  Y   Date-Time               Tdiff  
1   1       5   2012-06-11  13:10:30    0.00    
1   1       10  2012-06-11  15:10:30    2.00    
1   1       20  2012-06-11  17:10:30    2.00    
1   3       15  2012-06-11  13:20:30    0.00    
1   3       30  2012-06-11  14:20:30    1.00    
1   3       45  2012-06-11  17:20:30    3.00    
1   6       9   2012-06-11  13:35:30    0.00        
1   6       15  2012-06-11  15:35:30    2.00    
1   6       30  2012-06-11  18:35:30    3.00    
3   2       8   2012-06-11  13:50:30    0.00  
3   2       14  2012-06-11  14:55:30    1.083   
3   2       20  2012-06-11  16:55:30    2.00    
3   2       30  2012-06-11  19:00:30    2.083   
3   5       10  2012-06-11  13:40:30    0.00    
3   5       15  2012-06-11  16:45:30    3.083
```

ID - plant
IDaxis - plant leaf
Y - length of leaf
Date - Time - date and time of measurement
Tdiff - time(h) interval between measurement

I want to do:

1. sum up Tdiff for IDaxis in column SHORT$Ttot
2. calculate difference between row in Y for IDaxis in column SHORT$Ydiff
3. sum up Ydiff for IDaxis in column SHORT$Ytot

Code for:

1. `SHORT$Ttot  <- ave(SHORT$Tdiff, SHORT$IDaxis, FUN = cumsum)`works great
2. `SHORT$Ydiff <- ave(SHORT$Y,     SHORT$IDaxis, FUN = diff)`

Here I have a problem. Ydiff should looks like that (each first row for new IDxais is equal=0) :

```
ID  IDaxis  Y   Ydiff
1   1       5   0
1   1       10  5
1   1       20  10
1   3       15  0
1   3       30  15
1   3       45  15
1   6       9   0
```

But Ydiff looks like that:

```
ID  IDaxis  Y   Ydiff
1   1       5   5
1   1       10  10
1   1       20  -5
1   3       15  15
1   3       30  15
1   3       45  15
1   6       9  -36
```

This mess up all with code:

3.`SHORT$Ytot  <- ave(SHORT$Ydiff, SHORT$IDaxis, FUN = cumsum)`

If you could answer with a piece of code that would be very helpful.
*I have just start my work with R, but this is a simplified version of my dataframe - just to show the problem. I have three dataframes each 700 ID, each have 100 IDaxis and 25 variables.*

Comment: please always ?dput your data :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the function in the second `ave` command to:

```
function(x) c(0, diff(x))
```

This is necessary since the length of the output of `diff` is shorter than the original vector (difference of 1). Just add zeros to the vectors created by `diff`. This ensures that the first value of each subgroup is zero.

The complete code:

```
SHORT$Ttot <- ave(SHORT$Tdiff, SHORT$IDaxis, FUN = cumsum)
SHORT$Ydiff <- ave(SHORT$Y, SHORT$IDaxis, FUN = function(x) c(0, diff(x)))
SHORT$Ytot <- ave(SHORT$Ydiff, SHORT$IDaxis, FUN = cumsum)
```

The result:

```
   ID IDaxis  Y            Date.Time Tdiff  Ttot Ydiff Ytot
1   1      1  5 2012-06-11  13:10:30 0.000 0.000     0    0
2   1      1 10 2012-06-11  15:10:30 2.000 2.000     5    5
3   1      1 20 2012-06-11  17:10:30 2.000 4.000    10   15
4   1      3 15 2012-06-11  13:20:30 0.000 0.000     0    0
5   1      3 30 2012-06-11  14:20:30 1.000 1.000    15   15
6   1      3 45 2012-06-11  17:20:30 3.000 4.000    15   30
7   1      6  9 2012-06-11  13:35:30 0.000 0.000     0    0
8   1      6 15 2012-06-11  15:35:30 2.000 2.000     6    6
9   1      6 30 2012-06-11  18:35:30 3.000 5.000    15   21
10  3      2  8 2012-06-11  13:50:30 0.000 0.000     0    0
11  3      2 14 2012-06-11  14:55:30 1.083 1.083     6    6
12  3      2 20 2012-06-11  16:55:30 2.000 3.083     6   12
13  3      2 30 2012-06-11  19:00:30 2.083 5.166    10   22
14  3      5 10 2012-06-11  13:40:30 0.000 0.000     0    0
15  3      5 15 2012-06-11  16:45:30 3.083 3.083     5    5
```